# Access Data from Firestore and Put it in SwiftUI EnvironmentObject

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I am trying to use Firestore and get the data from the Firestore and then put it in EnvironmentObject. But it is not working out. I tried different approaches each ended with different errors.

Here is my code:

```
class FirebaseManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tweets: [Tweet] = []
    private let db: Firestore = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init() {
        
        db.collection("tweets")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
                if let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                let tweets = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({ document in
                    try? document.data(as: Tweet.self)
                })
                
                if let tweets {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tweets = tweets
                    }
                }
                
            }
    }
    
}
```

Then I try to call FirebaseManager in the code below:

```
struct HomeTimelineScreen: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    @StateObject private var firebaseManager = FirebaseManager()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        
        // ERROR  Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter
        firebaseManager.$tweets.sink { tweets in
            appState.tweets = tweets
        }
        
        
        // ERROR/WARNING ObservableObject of type AppState found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppState may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
        firebaseManager.$tweets.assign(to: \.appState.tweets, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
   
        
    }
```

The EnvironmentObject AppState is injected in the TwitterApp main file as shown below:

```
@main
struct TwitterAppApp: App {
    
    @ObservedObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
                LandingScreen()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                        switch route {
                        case .login:
                                LoginScreen().appLogoToolbar()
                        case .register:
                                RegistrationScreen().appLogoToolbar()
                        case .home:
                                HomeScreen()
                        case .detail(let tweet):
                                TweetDetailsScreen(tweet: tweet)
                        }
                    }
                   
            }.environmentObject(coordinator)
            .environmentObject(AppState())
        }
    }
}
```

AppState:

```
import Foundation

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tweets: [Tweet] = []
}
```

UPDATE: My biggest issue is on how to re-render the TweetDetailScreen since it is also using the TweetCellView.

```
struct TweetDetailsScreen: View {
    
    let tweet: Tweet
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            TweetCellView(tweet: tweet)
            
            ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(index)")
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

I took your advice and added single source of truth FirebaseManager and now it works as I want it to be.

```
 struct TweetDetailsScreen: View {
        
        @EnvironmentObject var firebaseManager: FirebaseManager
        let tweet: Tweet
        
        var body: some View {
            List {
                
                if let tweet = firebaseManager.findByDocumentId(tweet.documentID ?? "") {
                    TweetCellView(tweet: tweet)
                }
                
                ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                }
            }
        }
    }


class FirebaseManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tweets: [Tweet] = []
    private let db: Firestore = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init() {
        
        db.collection("tweets")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
                if let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                let tweets = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({ document in
                    try? document.data(as: Tweet.self)
                })
                
                if let tweets {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tweets = tweets
                    }
                }
                
            }
    }
    
    func findByDocumentId(_ documentId: String) -> Tweet? {
        guard let index = tweets.firstIndex(where: { $0.documentID == documentId }) else { return nil }
        return tweets[index]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you need TWO storages of `var tweets`? Did you read about "single source of truth"? No? Then better read. Just put `firebaseManager` as another `environmentObject` and use it directly.

Comment: Updated code. I added FirebaseManager to the environmentObject. Now when I go to detail screen I fetch the object from the firebase manager tweets collection and pass it to the TweetDetailView. This works as expected but it introduced findByDocumentId into the view.